# How to query db relationships in controller?

Tags: laravel-4

I have a single post I am querying by ID. Within that result, I have a column called "post_author" with an ID.

I have a users table (users) to get the authors information by the authorId. In this case, the column "name".

Here is my controller:

```
class PostsController extends BaseController {

public function index($id)
{

    return View::make('posts.post')->with('post', Post::find($id));

}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'post_author');
}
}
```

In my view, when I try to get the username in the view, it throws an error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'post_author');
}
```

this code is in the model. And users table fields username exists.

```
$post->user->username
```

In this way you can reach in view